# PHP function is not getting called

Tags: php

I can not figure out why this isn't working it all looks fine to. The checkData function isn't being called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    //if statement that go through all the functions
    if (checkData ($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $gender)) {}

    //function that checks if information given is valid
    function checkData($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $gender) {
        $legal = true;
        if (strlen($fname) < 1 || strlen($lname < 1) || strlen($password) < 8 || strlen($gender) < 1) {
            $legal = false;
        }

        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $legal = false;
        }

        return $legal;
    }
}
```

All the variables are correctly set.

Comment: If `checkData` isn't being called, the problem is before this.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain it's not being called? If you're running this via a web page, I'll wager you're just losing the 'debug1' string in a sea of HTML. You might put an `exit;` after the echo to make it more obvious. Or output to a debug file.

Comment: @Barmar but anything I put before the if statement works perfectly

Comment: Are `$fname, $lname, $email, $password, $gender` all defined?

Comment: @StackSlave Why would that matter? PHP doesn't abort on undefined variables.

Comment: @AlexHowansky that’s the thing all the html I do have isn’t appearing either

Comment: Use `View Source` to see the raw HTML being returned.

Comment: @StackSlave yes they are

Comment: @Barmar that would have mattered, because PHP throws errors on undefined variables... but they're defined, so ??????

Comment: @StackSlave PHP prints warnings on undefined variables, it doesn't stop the script.

Comment: @Barmar, so it may matter if that code is run above some HTML. Then you could *(but probably won't)* get a broken page, with `<br />` and `<b>` tags above `<html>`. Those tags show up, anyways.

Comment: There's not enough information here to figure out why it's not working. We need more context.

Comment: @Barmar I added the entire php part of the document and I am sure that the variables are all set.

Comment: How are you determining that `checkData()` isn't being called, did you try adding a `die('ded');` right as the first line inside the function?

Comment: @bdb8 It doesn't matter if the variables are set or not, as I said above.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib An earlier version of the question had an `echo` statement at the start of `checkData`

Comment: @Barmar I took that out for readability. This is everything that is not commented

Comment: are you sure `isset($_POST['submit'])` is true?

Comment: @Barmar yes, I tested that

Comment: Put `echo "before checkData";` and `echo "after checkData";` before and after the `if` statement to see if you're getting there.

Comment: @Barmar I did this already the one before works fine the one after doesn’t appear

Comment: The only way that could be happening is if `checkData` exits the script or something in the `if` block exits the script.

Comment: Try renaming the function? Maybe there is a name conflict or something?

Comment: Do you really have the function definition inside the `if` block?

Comment: If you do, you're getting an undefined function error and the script aborts. The function isn't defined until you execute the `function` line, but you're calling it before that.

Comment: @Barmar putting the function outside of the if worked thank you so much

Comment: check my updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

Define functions global (and in some languages at the top) like:

```
//function that checks if information given is valid
function checkData($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $gender) { 
    $legal = true;
        
    if (strlen($fname) < 1 || strlen($lname < 1) || strlen($password) < 8 || strlen($gender) < 1) {
        $legal = false;
    }
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $legal = false;
    }

    return $legal;
 }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    //if statement that go through all the functions
    if (checkData ($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $gender)) {

    }       

}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't care about the order of function definitions.

Comment: But you're right about not putting the function definition inside the `if`.

Comment: That's why I put it outside the if. I only put it on top, because its a habit for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to placed outside of the if(isset($_POST['submit']) block

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkData($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $gender) {        
  if((empty($fname)) OR (empty($lname)) OR (strlen($password) < 8) OR (empty($gender)) OR (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

And then call it this way:

```
if(checkData($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $gender)){
  // RETURNS TRUE... Process your code
}else{
  // RETURNS FALSE... Display error
}
```